# 404 Error when deployed in tomcat server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have deployed my java web application in tomcat (v 7.0) . It successfully deployed and also showed my index.jsp page. wen i try to call my restfull web services from rest client it is giving 404 error.

after deploying i got localhost:9090/mywebapp in browser

below is the url pattern i gave to rest webservices.

```
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
```

now i tried http://localhost:9090/mywebapp/webresources/myresource
in rest client. the tomcat is giving 404 error.

FYI: i am using jersy api for restfull web services

any suggestion is appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to use `/mywebapp/webresources/*` as the mapping?

Comment: i just tried to place /mywebapp/webresources/* in web.xml but not working still 404 error

Comment: Do you have a `/mywebapp/*` mapping in the same web.xml? Could be that servlet had taken over the request, thought it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you post your complete web.xml, all your jar/maven dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below check list might be useful: 
 1. make sure application running on the same http port 
 2. make sure application context path is same as you given 
 3. make sure the user have proper authorization to access service